# What does the '*all' in file.read for moonscript mean?

Tags: lua, moonscript

In moonscript, what does the `*all` when reading a file mean ?

Sample script:

```
file = io.open('README.md', "rb")
content = file\read("*all")
```

If there is a `*all` are there other pointers that reads half the file etc?

Answer (score 3):

It means what it says: read the whole file (actually, what is left of it).

No, there is no direct way to read half the file.

You can read a given number of bytes.

Comment: this is not a moonscript specific thing by the way, you can read about it in the Lua docs: https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html